# Fourier Series - Integration

Tags: fourier-series

Could someone explain where I am going wrong with the following fourier series calculation please?

I'm trying to compute the $A_{0}$ and $A_{n}$ coefficients for the fourier series:
\begin{align}
1+0.3\cos(4\pi x) = A_{0} + \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}A_{r}\cos(r\pi x) \quad 0\le x \le 1
\end{align}

I have extended the interval to $[-1,1]$ (hence $\tau=2$) to make the function periodic and even and then computed $A_{0}$ as follows:
\begin{align}
A_{0} &= \frac{2}{\tau} \int_{0}^{\tau/2} f(x) dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}(1+0.3\cos(4\pi x)) dx\\
&= \left[x-\tfrac{0.3}{4\pi}\sin(4\pi x) \right]_{0}^{1}\\
&= 1
\end{align}

On to $A_{n}$:
\begin{align}
A_{n} &= \frac{4}{\tau} \int_{0}^{\tau/2}(1+0.3\cos(4\pi x))\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi x}{\tau}\right) dx\\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{1} (1+0.3\cos(4\pi x))\cos(n\pi x) dx\\
&= 2\int_{0}^{1} \cos(n\pi x) dx + 2(0.3)\int_{0}^{1} \cos(4\pi x)\cos(n\pi x) dx\\
&= \frac{2}{n\pi}\left[\sin(n\pi x)\right]_{0}^{1} + 2(0.3)\int_{0}^{1} \cos(4\pi x)\cos(n\pi x) dx\\
&= 2(0.3)\left\{\left[\cos(4\pi x)\frac{\sin(n\pi x)}{n\pi}\right]_{0}^{1} + 4\pi\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(n\pi x)}{n\pi}\sin(4\pi x) \right\}\\
&= 2(0.3)\left\{4\pi\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(n\pi x)}{n\pi}\sin(4\pi x) \right\}
\end{align}

I'm now stuck as I'm left with two $\sin$ terms. Could anyone offer assistance please?

Many thanks,
John

Comment: Do you not see that this function is already developed on its Fourier series so just read the coefficients!

Comment: @sami-ben-romdhane Hi Sami, I did see that but it doesn't make sense in my mind. e.g. $A_1\cos(\pi x) + A_2\cos(2\pi x)$ etc. I want to be able to see how it becomes $0.3\cos(4\pi x)$.

Comment: @JohnSmith Do you know Taylor series? What is the Taylor series of the infinitely differentiable function $x^3 + 2x + 3$? Did you have to use the formula $a_n = f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^n/n!$ to calculate it? Now what can you say about the Fourier series of $4\cos(3\pi x) + 8\sin(6 \pi x) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to attack the integral over the cosines as follows.  First, consider the cosine addition formula:

$$\cos{(a + b)} = \cos{a} \cos{b} - \sin{a} \sin{b}$$
$$\cos{(a - b)} = \cos{a} \cos{b} + \sin{a} \sin{b}$$

$$\implies \cos{(a + b)} + \cos{(a - b)} = 2 \cos{a} \cos{b}$$

So...

$$\int_0^1 dx \, \cos{(4 \pi x)} \cos{(n \pi x)} = \frac12 \int_0^1 dx \, \cos{\left (n+4 \right )\pi x} +\frac12  \int_0^1 dx \, \cos{\left (n-4 \right )\pi x} $$

Note that $n \ge 1$.  Thus, you may convince yourself that the first integral on the RHS is zero, and the second one is zero except when...

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Many thanks Ron. Very clear. Does this then mean the expression $1+0.3\cos(4\pi x)$ cannot be written in terms of an infinite sum?

Comment: @JohnSmith: depend on what you mean by infinite sum.  Really, the infinite sum is over a function that is zero except for a single value of the index.  We call that a delta function, or a sifting function, which really just turns a sum or an integral into a function evaluated at a single point.  But all this is a bit more complex than it needs to be.  Just know that the integral over the cosines is zero except when $n=\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

If you will use a formula [List_of_trigonometric_identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) for  sin(A)*sin(b),
[image: formula]
 when you have 2 cases.
first case n=4 you can find that integral by using a formula for sin^2(x). Second case n not= 4 you will get for all n zero.
You will see that you already have the fourier series.

The infinite sum will become only one term.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not familiar with an identity which converts a product of sines into an addition of sine terms. What exactly are you referring to? Many thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith I fixed my answer . Hope it helps you find the coefficients $A_n$